# Understanding Prolog lists and recursion

Tags: list, recursion, prolog, reverse, tail-recursion

```
reverse([], X, X).
reverse([H|Original], Result, Reverse) :- 
   reverse(Original, Result, [H|Reverse]).

?- reverse([1,2,3], X, []).
X = [3,2,1].
```

So above is a fairly simple Prolog program to reverse a list. I'm just looking for someone to explain to me how the `Reverse` variable in the reverse rule ends up with the result. From my thinking, I'm adding the head of the original list to the head of a new list `Reverse` thus reversing the list. Nowhere am I interacting with the variable Result, so why does it hold anything at all?

I've been really stumped on this for a few days now and would be really grateful if anyone could clear this up!

PS. I'm also struggling with why `reverse([], X, X).` is required for this to work.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you activate tracing …

```
trace(reverse).
```

… then you can see what happens:

```
?- reverse([1,2,3],X,[]).
 T Call: (7) reverse([1, 2, 3], _G1003, [])
 T Call: (8) reverse([2, 3], _G1003, [1])
 T Call: (9) reverse([3], _G1003, [2, 1])
 T Call: (10) reverse([], _G1003, [3, 2, 1])
 T Exit: (10) reverse([], [3, 2, 1], [3, 2, 1])
 T Exit: (9) reverse([3], [3, 2, 1], [2, 1])
 T Exit: (8) reverse([2, 3], [3, 2, 1], [1])
 T Exit: (7) reverse([1, 2, 3], [3, 2, 1], [])
X = [3, 2, 1].
```

In your example the second rule builds the reversed list and the first rule "copies" the `Reverse` list to the `Result` variable.

Comment: Thanks!, I guess the problem I was having was understanding the relationship between the two rules